# How to run System.cmd in parallel

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to start these two commands in mix task:

```
System.cmd("cmd.exe", ["/c", "mix phx.server"], into: IO.stream(:stdio, :line))
System.cmd("cmd.exe", ["/c", "npm run dev"], cd: ".\\frontend", into: IO.stream(:stdio, :line))
```

However, both of them are blocking therefore, despite the order, second one never gets executed. How do I start both of them at once?

Comment: I think the common way to achieve this in Phoenix is to configure [`watchers`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Endpoint.html#module-runtime-configuration) in your `Endpoint` config, in `config/dev.exs`. This way `phx.server` will start the frontend for you in your dev env.

Answer (score 2):

While the comment above by @sabiwara is absolutely correct, I am to address the exact problem stated explicitly.

One might use [`Task.async/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#module-async-and-await) or even just [`spawn/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#spawn/3):

```elixir
spawn(
  System, 
  :cmd,
  ["cmd.exe", ["/c", "mix phx.server"], into: IO.stream(:stdio, :line)]
)
spawn(
  System,
  :cmd, 
  ["cmd.exe", ["/c", "npm run dev"],
    cd: ".\\frontend", into: IO.stream(:stdio, :line)]
)
```